# how to filter List of <File> using lambda by file extensions?

Tags: java, lambda

I have tried the following:

```
List<File> part;
List<File> csvFiles = part.stream().filter(f -> f.getName().endsWith("csv")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But I am getting error  "`Syntax error on tokens(s), misplaced construct(s)`"

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem, and the complete and exact error message you get.

Comment: Hi, would you consider posting a [MCVE] please?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<File> filesList = new ArrayList<>();
// retrieve all files and fill the fileList
List<File> csvFiles = new ArrayList<>();
csvFiles = files.stream().filter(file -> 
        file.getAbsolutePath().contains(".csv")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for providing code which might help solve the problem, but generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem.